# Server side attribute not available in Silverlight client

Tags: c#, silverlight, attributes

I have a custom attribute:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

It's declared in a file called `MyCustomAttribute.shared.cs`, which has made the class visible on the client as it comes up in auto-complete/InteliSense on the client.

I have added it to a property on my class which is an `Entity` returned from the database and passed to the Silverlight client by WCF RIAServices:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]
    [Display(ResourceType=typeof(ResourceFile), Name="ResourceName")]
    [MyCustom]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try and see if the property has the attribute attached it's not present on the list:

```
PropertyInfo prop = GetProperty(myType, "MyProperty");
object[] attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
foreach (object attribute in attributes)
{
    if (attribute is MyCustomAttribute)
    {
        // Do my stuff here
    }
}
```

None of the attributes returned are `MyCustomAttribute`.

I've checked the generated code on the client side and for this property it looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the 'BarcodeNumber' value.
    /// </summary>
    [ConcurrencyCheck()]
    [DataMember()]
    [Display(Name="ResourceName", ResourceType=typeof(ResourceFile))]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]
    [RoundtripOriginal()]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        ....
    }
```

So, clearly my attribute isn't being copied to the client.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that I was missing was that I need a write a custom code generator to extend the default one so it can recognise my new attribute.

The process is documented in various places on the web:

[.NET - WCF RIA Services code generatie naar je hand zetten](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET36) (the article is in English)

[T4 Code Generator for WCF RIA Services](https://varunpuranik.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/t4-code-gen/)

However, we decided that this would be overkill to implement for just one attribute on one property so have used a different approach (based on business logic) to implement the functionality we need.